# How to change props (variant) of a material-ui Button?

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui

I have a row of buttons and want to change the Button component to be 'contained' when clicked and 'text' otherwise. Also when one button is clicked, others should go back to normal. I tried adding onClick handler to the button component and getting the state change but it is very confusing. Since I am new to React, would appreciate a code snippet to help.
Below is the code I tried but getting error "TypeError: Unable to get property 'red' of undefined or null reference":

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

let initialState = {
    red: false,
    blue: false,
    green: false
};

export default function Home() {

   const [initialState, setState] = useState();

   const handleClick = (name) => event => {
   switch(name){
      case 'Red': initialState.red = true; break;
      case 'Blue': initialState.blue = true; break;
      case 'Green': initialState.green = true; break;
      default: break;
   }
   setState(initialState);
 }

 return (
    <div className="Home">
      <Button onClick={handleClick("Red")} variant={initialState.red ? "contained" : "text"}> Red </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClick("Blue")} variant={initialState.blue ? "contained" : "text"} > blue </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClick("Green")} variant={initialState.green ? "contained" : "text"} > green </Button>
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: I think you have implemented it correctly. Can you post a bit of code too?

Comment: Also are you sure you want to change the prop of the button on click? Or you want to change the background of the button(not prop) onClick? Because it may happen you are changing the prop of the button only to change the background appearance of the button

Comment: Modified the question for more info...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using hooks with react https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-frog-du5s1.

Though it sounds like you want toggle buttons. If you are using the latest material-ui this is a component they already have built out https://material-ui.com/components/toggle-button/. If you wish to alter the appearance you can checkout the CSS API for the individual components involved.

**Edit:** Here is the updated sandbox w/ comments based on the info you gave https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-dhawan-ysjgk

Also you never loaded your `initialState` into the hook `useState(initialState )` which would be why you got that error.

Important to read the following note in the docs on useState here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates to ensure your updates work `onClick`. Could probably even use the `useReducer` hook for this.

Comment: This works. However has a problem of having one such function & state for each button. I rather wanted to have single click handler and set the state accordingly. Plus I also wanted the other buttons to go back to normal when one is clicked. I have updated the question with code snippet. But I am getting errot "TypeError: Unable to get property 'red' of undefined or null reference". Please help

Comment: P.S. - I don't want to use toggle buttons.

Comment: @VitthalKulkarni I updated my sandbox and explanation

Comment: Great! It worked just as expected. Thank you for the help. I will definitely go through the documentation you referred and clear my concepts. Thanks again.